# A systemd timer rule

Tags: systemd

I want run a program make it start on the **2019-08-14 13:00:00**.

After this, run it every 4,096 minutes.

I know the **/integer** can repeat per min. But It's wrong to write it like this:

```
OnCalendar=2019-08-14 13:00/4096:00 UTC
```

Seems to be 4096 minutes is not allowed. Error: Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: 2019-08-14 13:8/4096:00 UTC

Does anyone know how to implement？

Comment: :00 after minutes is not important, If I change 00 to 12 or other number, It's still wrong, and the big question is, is the maximum number of repeats per minute 60, or 59? Anyway, 4096 minutes is not allowed.

Comment: `4096:00` should be 4096 hours, not minutes

Comment: The way I read the systemd.time(7) man page, the repetition should read `.../4096m` - maybe try that? Untested.

Answer (score 2):

The `/` syntax in systemd calendar specifications only applies to the specific field being evaluated. It's similar to the `*` syntax, which allows every value of the field and is often equivalent to a `/1` for repeating every 1 unit of that field.

This is also similar to cron, some cron implementations allow a similar `/` syntax (slightly different, needs an interval, for example `5-59/8`) and a `*` syntax as well.

The documentation of [systemd.time(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#) mentions `*` and `/` together and uses the term **match**, which strongly implies the restriction on that field only:

> In the date and time specifications, any component may be specified as "`*`" in which case any value will match. Alternatively, each component can be specified as a list of values separated by commas. Values may be suffixed with "`/`" and a repetition value, which indicates that the value itself and the value plus all multiples of the repetition value are matched. Two values separated by "`..`" may be used to indicate a range of values; ranges may also be followed with "`/`" and a repetition value.

So unfortunately it's not really possible to use a single calendar specification that repeats every 4096 minutes.

One option is to use different settings of timer units, for instance [`OnUnitActiveSec=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnActiveSec=), which will trigger the timer a certain interval after the unit associated with it is active. Since triggering the timer will activate the unit, this results in a periodic repeated triggering, at the interval of your choice.

You can combinate that with a calendar event, so it's first triggered on that calendar event and then repeated through the `OnUnitActiveSec=` rule. Note that this might stop if the machine reboots, in which case the unit needs to be triggered once to get the cycle rolling, which you can do using, for example, `OnBootSec=`. (Another option to work across reboots is to set the [`Persistent=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Persistent=) attribute.)